# Как правильно работать с COM объектами?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, com, office

Как правильно работать с COM-объектами из управляемого кода в C#?

Вот, к примеру, я выполняю некоторые операции interop access, но после того, как я закончил работу с Access, он продолжает висеть в процессах до тех пор, пока я не закрою саму программу.

Что я делаю не так?

Я пытался принудительно собирать мусор, но не помогло.

Comment: Покажите, как именно вы работаете.

Comment: Как-то так: http://codeshare.io/vCVSm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо освободить все ссылки на [RCW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8bwh56xe(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(comObject);
```

или

```
while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(comObject) > 0){}
```

Answer (score 1):

У COM объекта нужно вызвать метод для освобождения ресурсов.

Примерно так:

```
if (application != null)
{
   application.WorkbookBeforeClose -= new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler(application_WorkbookBeforeClose);
   application.Quit();
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   process.WaitForExit(100);
}
```

Comment: Если я обрабатываю коллекцию объектов в foreach, то должен ли я в конце итерации освобождать память?

Comment: Покажите код цикла.

Comment: @iluxa1810 скорее всего вы просто не вызываете `.Quit()` или `.Quit(0)`. Из приложения надо явно выходить в коде.

Comment: А если я работаю с коллекцией объектов COM через for each, то должен их в конце цикла освобождать через ReleaseComObject? Допустим я обрабатываю коллекцию запросов из Access.

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте метод `GC.Collect()`, реализуйте деструктор для освобождения памяти, и не стоит освобождать память/удалять обьекты в foreach

**Обновление**

```
class YourClass
{
    ~YourClass()  // destructor
    {
        /* лучше всего использовать unmanaged код для освобождения   памяти из под COM обьектов , в стиле C/C++
       */
    }
}
```

Comment: как в C# выглядят деструкторы, освобождающие память?

Comment: ~YourClass() не освобождает память, выделенную под этот класс. а для освобождения unmanaged-ресурсов нужно использовать не деструкторы, а паттерн dispose/finalize.

Comment: т.е. вообще есть случаи, когда дело действительно в нехватке финализатора, но при работе с PIA обычно просто не хватает явного выхода из приложения :(